# Socket connection from PC to Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

So here's what I'm trying to do: I have an Android app that uses a `ServerSocket` and I need to connect to this socket from my computer.

I've tried to get my IP address using `adb shell ifconfig` and I can ping this IP from the emulator's shell but I can't ping it from my computer's terminal.

In other words, how can I use Postman to connect on my emulator's web server?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Yes look I have answered my own question. If you need more help feel free to open a question and post it here, I'll see it I can answer it

Comment: Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970267/socket-communication-between-android-and-windows actually i want to send message from my Winfrom app to socket server application in emulator

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot but in Winform side i'm using SimpleTCP dll looks like i can connect but i cannot send message when i disconnect emulator gets my message

Comment: Hi Could you check my question?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution. It seems that if you want to communicate from your computer to your emulator, the IP address to use is `127.0.0.1` and you need to do some port forwarding using ADB in command line.

For example if you emulator is running a server on port `8080`

`adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`

Then call it with `localhost:8080`