# Socket communication between Android and Windows

Tags: android, winforms, sockets

Is it possible to Android Emulator will be socket server and Windows form app will be client and they communicate each other?

My emulator IP address is 192.168.232.2 but i cannot ping from my pc and i cannot connect via my winform app

What can i do?

Comment: That is pretty complicated and not eadily done. You better reverse server/client or use a real Android device.

Comment: @blackapps i know it's complicated because of i'm asking

Comment: You have not mentioned in the subject that you have the server on an emulator.

Comment: And in the developer files of google its explaine in a page for the emulator.

Comment: Please read subject! I named subject! That the first people see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a ServerSocket in your Android code, you can assign a port to it by passing it, for example here I'm opening a `ServerSocket` on the port 8080:

```kotlin
    val serverSocket = ServerSocket(8080)
```

You then need to use `adb` to forward incoming connection to your emulator, by running, here forwarding the port 8080 again

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

At this point any connection to your PC on port 8080 will be forwarded to your emulator.

You can get the IP by typing in the terminal `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` depending on your operating system.

The easiest way to test it is to run both client and server on your PC and just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the IP address.